# How to negate the 'Allow from env' in Apaches htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I want to restrict the access with a specific domain with htaccess. At first I am trying to deny the access to my restricted-domain.com, and then I will implement the "login".

```
# set the "require_auth" var if Host ends with "example2.com"
SetEnvIfNoCase Host restricted-domain\.com$ require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /html/typo3/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
#require valid-user
#or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

This ends in 403 on both domains. So I commented Deny from all and checked in my PHP whether the variable require_auth is set or not. This was correct, it was NULL at the public domain and true on the restricted. So I tried it without the negation:

```
Allow from env=require_auth
```

This works great except that it behaves the opposite way. I cant flip the logic, because there are many public domains and they will vary in the future. So how can I negate the Allow from env directive?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I flipped the whole logic, but it doesnt work. I am getting a 500 on the restricted domain, but I think, that isn't the htaccess. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `require_auth` variable in your `SetEnvIfNoCase` for restricted-domain
2. Reset `require_auth` variable if host is not `restricted-domain`
3. finally flip allow,deny

Try this code:

```
# set the "require_auth" var if Host ends with "example2.com"
SetEnvIfNoCase Host restricted-domain\.com$ require_auth
SetEnvIfNoCase Host (?!restricted-domain\.com).* !require_auth

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /html/typo3/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Satisfy any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=require_auth
```